# GalleryView - filmstrip navigation w/o changing a picture in a panel

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, galleryview

How to navigate thru [GalleryView](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) filmstrip without changing a picture in a panel? I can not find a property for this.

GalleryView is pretty popular so I hope, someone will know how to do it simple. It is always possibility to change the gallery code, but I hope there is better solution. Some flag maybe?

Currently I have the following settings:

```
$('#gallery').galleryView({
panel_width: 600,
panel_height: 300,
frame_width: 120,
frame_height: 75,
transition_interval: 0,
background_color: '#222',
border: 'none',
easing: 'easeInOutBack',
pause_on_hover: true,
nav_theme: 'custom',
overlay_height: 52,
filmstrip_position: 'top',
overlay_position: 'top',
nav_theme: 'dark',
frame_scale: 'crop',
frame_opacity: 0.7,
start_frame: 2,
fade_panels: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `transition_interval: -1`.

0 as you have specified indicates no interval so as soon as transition has ended the next one starts.

Comment: Sorry, but this is false answer. I had one image on my filmstrip and i thought it worked, but then when i had many images, the javascript had an infinite loop. Sorry.